# IMC 2001 second day problem 1, unclear "official" solution

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, systems-of-equations

I'm having trouble understanding the last part of [the "official" proof of the first problem](https://imc-math.org.uk/imc2001/prob_sol2.pdf) of the imc 2001:

> [image: image link]

I don't understand why if $a_0b_1+a_1b_0=1 \Rightarrow b_1+a_1=1$ imply that one of the two ($b_1$ or $a_1$) should be $1$ and the other should be $0$ and why they can't be for example $\frac{1}{2}$.

I've tried combining some equations to get for example something like $a_1b_1$ in it, but it didn't work out.

Comment: The solution is a bit terse. See [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2324712p18598246) for [more discussion](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h589688p3492212).

Comment: Once it is clear that $a_0=b_0=1$, it follows that $a_1 b_{s-1}+a_2 b_{s-2}+\cdots=0$. Using non-negativity this means that either $a_1=0$ or $b_{s-1}=0$ and so on from the first highlighted equation and $b_1=0$ or $a_{r-1}=0$ and so on from the second. Now $a_0 b_1+a_1 b_0=1$ reduces to $a_1+b_1=1$ so $a_1=1$ and $b_1=0$ or vice-versa. Then proceed by induction. E.g., in the next step one would similarly get $a_2+b_2=1$ and so on.

Comment: Perfect Solution , @AnCar !

Comment: Yes, i tried that as well but I didn't see why (and I still don't) $a_{r-1}$ and $b_{s-1}$ can't be both $0$.

Comment: Them being both $0$ does not contradict what the problem asks you to prove.

Comment: Yes but than couldn't you say $a_1=\frac{1}{2}=b_1$? That wouldn't contradict the other statement since $b_{s-1}=0=a_{r-1}$

Comment: Oh sorry, that is a good point. However, consider the coefficient of $x^{r+s-1}$ in the product. That is $a_{r-1}+b_{s-1}$ and this must be $1$ by assumption.

Comment: Oh yes, that's the part I was missing. Many thanks!